# Proof of equivalence of $\lambda$ norms in Sobolev space $H_0^1(\Omega)$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces, equivalent-metrics

Consider the following metrics in $H_0^1(\Omega)$ with $\Omega$ a bounded domain:

$$\| u\|_\lambda=\left( \int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2+\lambda\int_\Omega u^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$ and $$\| u\|_0=\left( \int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$ so that
$$\| u\|^2_\lambda=\| u\|^2_0+\lambda |u|^2_2.$$

Satisfying $\lambda > -\lambda_1$ with $\lambda_1$ the first eigenvalue of $\Delta u+\lambda u=0$ or the optimal constant in Poincaré's inequality:
$$|u|_2\leq \lambda_1^{-\frac{1}{2}}\|u\|_0$$

I am to prove there are $C_1,C_2>0$ so that $$C_1\|u\|_0\leq \| u\|_\lambda \leq C_2 \| u\|_0$$ for all $u\in H_0^1$.

The right inequality is easy to prove applying Poincaré's Inequality to $\| u\|^2_\lambda=\| u\|^2_0+\lambda |u|^2_2$; the condition $\lambda > -\lambda_1$ ensures $C_2=\sqrt{1+\frac{\lambda}{\lambda_1}}$ is well defined.

How would I go about proving the other inequality?

Comment: So $\lambda$ is not necessarily positive. How do you prove that $\|.\|_\lambda$ is a norm ?

Comment: For $\lambda>-\lambda_1$ you can check that the properties are satisfied.

Comment: Aha, I missed this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The case $\lambda \ge 0$ is clear.

Let $\lambda < 0$. From Poincaré, you find
$$-\lambda \, |u|_2^2 \le \lambda_1 \, |u|_2^2 \le \|u\|_0^2$$
Hence, for $\alpha > 0$
$$\|u\|_0^2 \le (1+\alpha)\, \|u\|_0^2 - \alpha \, \|u\|_0^2 \le (1+\alpha) \|u\|_0^2 - \alpha \, \lambda_1 \|u\|_2^2.$$
Now, choose $\alpha$ such that $-\alpha \, \lambda_1 = (1+\alpha) \, \lambda$, i.e., $\alpha = -\lambda/(\lambda+\lambda_1)$. Then, $\alpha > 0$ since $\lambda < 0 < \lambda + \lambda_1$. This gives
$$\|u\|_0^2 \le (1+\alpha) \|u\|_0^2 + (1+\alpha) \,\lambda \|u\|_2^2 = (1+\alpha) \, \|u\|_\lambda^2.$$

Comment: But this shows that $\| u\|_0^2 \leq \| u\|_0^2 + \| u\|^2_\lambda$ so in turn $0\leq \| u\|^2_\lambda$ which doesnt tell me anything.

Comment: @alonsos: My fault. You have to change the constants a little bit. Now it should work.